# Why both of the method go wrong in extracting and sum the numbers in a text?

Tags: python, numbers, sum

The goal is summing all the numbers in a text ,using `re.findall()`.

I tried two methods,both of which run ok ,while none of them gave out the true sum.And their outcomes seem to be smaller than the correct total number.The sample.txt is made up of several lines consisted of words and numbers, such as "3036 many reasons, ranging from making your living to solving 7209".

Could you please help me find the problem？And what should be the correct code?

Solution 1:

```
import re
hand = open ('sample.txt')
numlist = list ()
for line in hand :
    line = line.rstrip()
    stuff = re.findall ('[0-9]+',line)
    if len(stuff) != 1 :continue
    num=int(stuff[0])
    numlist.append(num)
b=sum(numlist)
print (b)
```

Solution 2:

```
import re
hand = open ('sample.txt')
s=0
for line in hand :
    line = line.rstrip()
    stuff = re.findall ('[0-9]+',line)
    if len(stuff) != 1 :continue
    s +=int(stuff[0])
print (s)
```

Comment: What does sample.txt look like?

Comment: will there be only one number in a line like `100`

Comment: The text is made up of letters and numbers, and may consist of several numbers in the same line, such as "3036 many reasons, ranging from making your living to solving 7209"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just apply `re.findall` against the whole file..

```
hand = open ('sample.txt')
print sum([int(i) for i in re.findall(r'\d+', hand.read())])
hand.close()
```

Comment: Thank you. But I cannot run this code in python 3.It turned out with a syntax error.

Comment: @jellyfishhuang in Python 3 the function `print` needs the `parentheses ()` so the second line of this answer would be `print(sum([int(i) for i in re.findall(r'\d+', hand.read())]))`

Comment: @makeMonday Thank you! :)